# PHP Array: Assigning different keys to values

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I know this is a simple concept (albeit one I struggle with) but I have some latitude and longitude data. It is read from a .data file (not as a .db, not my choice) and here is what I have so far:

```
$current_data = file("/my_data_file.data");
$latest_data = array();
foreach ($current_data as $entry)
{
  $latest_data[] = $entry;
}

$latest_data = preg_replace("!\r?\n!", "", $latest_data);
echo json_encode($latest_data);
```

This outputs the data like so (didn't paste all of it here to save your eyes from bleeding):

*["-118.510 33.896 ","-120.762 32.826 ","-122.959 31.716 ","-125.104 30.570 ","-127.198 29.389 ","-129.243 28.175 ","-131.243 26.931 ","-133.198 25.660 ","-135.112 24.362 ","-136.988 23.041 "]*

So it's one giant array, each lat/long pair separated by a comma and each pair within quotations.

I've googled this and there is a ton of information on php arrays and key/values, but what's the right way to do it? I find myself making this much more complicated than it needs to be.

Assuming in the `foreach` loop it'll be something like

`$latest_data[] = array('latitude' => $entry[the_lat_number], 'longitude' => $entry[the_long_number]);`

Any input on the matter is appreciated.

**Update**: example of the data viewed in VIM (It doesn't visually appear there IS a whitespacing issue, but based on using `explode`, there does seem to be).

[image]

Comment: What's your exact question? Why does `$latest_data[] = array('latitude' => $entry[the_lat_number], 'longitude' => $entry[the_long_number]);` not work?

Comment: You said you are "assuming it will be something like...", did you try it at all?

Comment: @Reeno well I'm not going to manually enter the lat or long, that doesn't make any sense. @cillosis Yes of course. It seemed `explode` was a decent approach but with the inconsistent whitespace I'm not too sure if that is best.

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_data = file("/my_data_file.data");
$latest_data = array();
foreach ($current_data as $entry)
{
  list($lat,$lng) = explode(" ",$entry);
  $latest_data[] = array('lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng);
}
```

Now your json data should look something like this:

```
[{lat: xx, lng: xx},...]
```

Comment: There must be a spacing issue in the .data file (which I don't have permission to access): because the above returns lat, but no long `[{"lat":"-118.510","lng":""},{"lat":"-120.762","lng":""},{"lat":"-122.959","lng":""}]`

Comment: Look in the file and see how it is delimited. I just assumed that it would be space, given the resulting json you posted. Maybe you can expand your question with a sample of the data file ( like one or two lines )

Comment: Updated original question with attached image.

Comment: It looks like the data is delimeted by multiple spaces or maybe space / tabs.  Do this inside your foreach loop: print_r(explode(" ",$entry));  and you'll be able to see exactly how the lines are delimited. Then adjust your explode function accordingly. It looks like lat and long are separated by four spaces

Comment: Yeah I just messed with this: http://codeshare.io/d4FPp but I'm thinking I have to use `preg_split` instead of explode. Let me know your thoughts (you can edit that codeshare/write comments and I'll be able to see them).

Comment: If the format of your data is not going to change ( Why should it ? ) then use explode(). Otherwise go ahead and use preg_split()

Answer (score 0):

Using your code to add each pair as subarray is good approach. This way you'll be able to easily access data from each row like that `$latest_data[3]['latitude']` (to get latitude from fourth row).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ended up using `preg_split` instead of `explode` and all seems ok:

```
$current_data = file("/tmp/navhome/data/path_tail.data");

$latest_data = array();
foreach ($current_data as $entry) {
  $coords = preg_split("/ +/", $entry);
  $latest_data[] = array('latitude' => $coords[0], 'longitude' => $coords[1]);

}

echo json_encode($latest_data);
```

This is airplane data that gets updated when the flight path changes so it seemed `preg_split` was more appropriate.

This is outputting the data like so:

*[{"latitude":"-118.510","longitude":"33.896"},{"latitude":"-120.762","longitude":"32.826"},{"latitude":"-122.959","longitude":"31.716"}]*

Appreciate the input from everyone. Criticisms are welcome on this solution.